# swift for iOS - "setValue forUndefinedKey This class is not value coding for undefined key" error after renaming project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im having this error pop up after running an app and the moment launch screen is over i get this error.
[image: The error looks like this]

All I did before was renaming the project here:
[image: Thats where I renamed my project]

Answers to questions with the same error tell me to check all the links from my storyboard file, but as far as I can see none of them are problematic:
[image: Links from storyboard to view controller]
Also I tried creating a new project and pasting all the files there, which didn't work

Comment: Break that connection and re-connect it

Comment: I did that already, didn't help

Comment: The exception tells you that you have an instance of `UIViewController`, not your view controller subclass. The custom view controller subclass in your storyboard scene can't be found at runtime. Probably it is referring to your old project name as the module. Reset the the custom class for the view controller in your storyboard scene.

Answer (score -1):

So, as one of commenters pointed out, the classes for view controller in stroyboard were UIViewController, while the class I used were custom ViewController and SettingsViewController. All I had to do was to go in my stroyboard and set the module from which these controllers come to the current one